# handling of __attribute__ ((weak)) is different in clang and gcc

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang

I have an application (app) and a dynamic library/shared object (dlib), both are linked against a static library which declares a global variable (gvar) in a header file using `__declspec (selectany)` / `__attribute__ ((weak))`. By design both app and dlib should have their own copies of gvar (on MSVC and GCC I get exactly that).

After porting to Mac OSX and compiling with clang I see that gvar in dlib is linked to gvar in app. Not sure if this is a clang bug or by design; if it is by design, is there any way to avoid it and get the same behaviour as in GCC/MSVC?

clang version:

```
bash-3.2$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Minimal project to reproduce the issue:

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

__attribute__ ((weak)) int g_global = 10;

int main ()
{
    printf ("main (): g_global: addr = %p; value = %d\n", &g_global, g_global);

    typedef void Foo ();

    void* so = dlopen ("./my-so.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
    Foo* foo = (Foo*) dlsym (so, "foo");
    foo ();
}
```

shared.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__ ((weak)) int g_global = 20;

extern "C" void foo ()
{
    printf ("foo (): g_global: addr = %p; value = %d\n", &g_global, g_global);
}
```

build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f my-so.so
rm -f app.

c++ -shared -fPIC shared.cpp -omy-so.so
c++ main.cpp -oapp -ldl
```

output:

```
bash-3.2$ ./app
main (): g_global: addr = 0x10c657030; value = 10
foo (): g_global: addr = 0x10c657030; value = 10
```

Note that if I remove **attribute** ((weak)) then app and dlib get their own copies of gvar.

Comment: You say "by design" but it doesn't like very good design.  Can't you rewrite it to avoid exposing this symbol in such a complicated way?

Comment: If the global state IS required, than having separate copies of global variables for application and shared object is the most natural design. Having separate copies for global variables for each shared object is the default behaviour — even in clang without __attribute__ ((weak)). If nobody suggests anything better, that's how I will fix it: I will remove __attribute__ ((weak)) and do the old-school "extern int g_global;" in .h; and "int g_global;" in ".cpp".
But we have digressed, the actual question was "if this is a clang bug and if not, then is there an option to get gcc behaviour”.

Comment: You say "global", however shared/dynamic libraries are mapped into the address space of the process, so if they have separate copies of the variable, how is this "global"?  That behaviour is counter intuitive to me.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

To get the behaviour I want, I had to add `-fvisibility=hidden` to command line and add `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` to the symbols which need to be exported.